# Python :: initializing an object

Tags: python, formatting

I'm styding the object oriented features of Python. So far, I've only really used NumPy and SciPy and not the pure Python itself. I've written this small snippet of code:

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x = 0.0, y = 0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '%.2d , %.2d' % (self.x, self.y)

    def print_point(self):
        print('%.1d , %1.d' % (self.x,self.y))

a = Point()
b = Point(1.2,4.5)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Now the output is:

```
00 , 00
01 , 04
```

This seems like a classic formatting error to me, since the output should really be (0.0, 0.0) and (1.2, 4.5).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to use `"%.2f"` instead of `"%.2d"`

Comment: Did you want parentheses? Because if you want parentheses, you'll need to put them in. Python can't tell you want parentheses around your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it from `"%.2d"` to `"%.2f"`. Although I suggest that you use format instead of the old style of formatting.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0:.2f}, {1:.2f}'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def print_point(self):
        print('%.1d , %1.d' % (self.x, self.y))


a = Point()
b = Point(1.2, 4.5)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Gives you:

```
0.00, 0.00
1.20, 4.50
```

Answer (score 3):

just change your **str** to:
`def __str__(self):
        return '%.2f , %.2f' % (self.x, self.y)`

remember: %d prints an integer , %f prints a floating point value.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is formatting as an integer. You want `%f` - see here [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations)

but that is old-style.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{:.2f} , {:.2f}".format(self.x,self,y)
```

would be the modern approach.